# How can I prevent this script from being freely accessed?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a simple PHP/MySQL message system. The following code is a section of the page that displays the messages a user has received, `messages.php`. The user's messages have been fetched from MySQL and stored in the variable `$messages`.

```
foreach($messages as $message) {
    // formatting, printing the text, etc.
    echo '<a href="msg_del.php?id=' . $message['id'] . '">Remove</a>';
}
```

And here is the file `msg_del.php`:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Connect to the database
require("../info/dbinfo.php");
$db_user = constant("DB_USER");
$db_pass = constant("DB_PASS");
$db_name = constant("DB_NAME");
$db_server = constant("DB_SERVER");

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = " . $conn->quote($id) . ";");
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error connecting to database!";
    exit();
}

// Redirect to messages page
header("Location: messages.php");
exit();
?>
```

The code is fully functional, but the problem is that anyone can type `msg_del.php?id=SOMEID` into a browser and delete messages. How can I secure this to where messages can only be deleted from the links on `messages.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need some sort of token in your request to validate that this is indeed a valid request from your system.

One method would be to append a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) to your request. This ensures that the request came from a form you control, and someone isn't using an old form to spoof a new request.

There are [many nonce libraries for PHP](http://phptrends.com/dig_in/nonce) you can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to know if the current user has permission to do the action. One simple way to do that is with the $_SESSION variable.

Something like:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && /*permission logic here*/) {
    //display an error message
    die();
}

// database query here
```